# Como não enviar muitos registros ao clicar muitas vezes no button

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho um button, onde eu já vi vários tópicos e uma das soluções ela desativa, mas não envia os dados.

Código do button:

```html
<button onclick="this.disabled = true; this.form.submit(); return true;" name="enviar">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: Amigo, acho que um <input type="submit" value="Enviar" /> resolveria seu problema, substitua seu button pelo input a cima :D

Answer (score 0):

Veja [este exemplo funcional](http://jsfiddle.net/devillers/fr7gmbcy/) usando jQuery, tirado de outra pergunta do [SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15529882/2387977).

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $(this).find('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Se o problema é relacionado às requisições ajax, outra forma é o método `one`.

Veja:

```
$('form').one('submit', function()
{
   // Meu ajax é chamado aqui 
});
```